# Sequence's protocol required method

Tags: swift, protocols

**Sequence's protocol**

is a Swift protocol, so all the methods it are required.

Taking a look at its declaration, I've seen now that there are a lot of methods such as

```
makeIterator(), map(), filter()
```

and so on...

I'm wondering why **only**

*makeIterator()*

method is required.

It's not a **@objc** protocol with optional keyword, it's not a protocol's extension, it doesn't not conform any other protocols. It's a simple Swift kind of protocol.

Any idea?

Comment: "it's not a protocol's extension" – No, `Sequence` does provide default implementations for the rest of its requirements, e.g `map`'s [default implementation is here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da069590de164b7d4a0355cd621dc7153869c70d/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L831), `filter`'s [default implementation is here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da069590de164b7d4a0355cd621dc7153869c70d/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L867). Note that there's also a default implementation for `makeIterator()` when the sequence is its own iterator.

Comment: Oh man! I was looking for the default implementation inside the same file but I was not able to find it. In fact above, I have written that it's not a protocol's extension because of I was finding the default implementation inside that file. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hamish Seems like a perfectly valid answer, why not posting it?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the question, [Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976878/hamish) gives us the right solution

> it's not a protocol's extension" – No, Sequence does provide default
>   implementations for the rest of its requirements, e.g map's default
>   implementation is [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da069590de164b7d4a0355cd621dc7153869c70d/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L831), filter's default implementation is [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da069590de164b7d4a0355cd621dc7153869c70d/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L867). Note
>   that there's also a default implementation for makeIterator() when the
>   sequence is its own iterator.

We can found the `makeIterator()` default implementation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L627)

Really thanks!